# Google Nearby notification URL's and https

Tags: http, https, google-nearby

I see today that Google Nearby notifications limit URL's to only point to valid http**s**(secure) sites. I understand your desire to support secure websites but with Nearby opening up the world for a lot of SMB customers who sometimes don't have their content on https sites, have you considered allowing non-secure sites that may not have a certificate installed? This is becoming an impediment for nearby adoption for some of our smaller customers that lack secure sites. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing that feature for non-https website will reduce the security of users: http website can't be safe.

Today the migration to https is more simple than before. Certificate can be free, renewals automated, with [letsencrypt.org](http://letsencrypt.org) for example

Comment: Totally understand that it's not a big deal to install certificates. But if you're a service provider trying to enable Nearby for your customers, it becomes very hard to convince the customer to install certificates. Sometimes, it's not even about costs. And educating every customer is very painful. But I understand how Google does not want to encourage pointing to insecure sites.